# grails sends 500 response after ten seconds for async

Tags: grails

I am experimenting with async responses using Grails. I've noticed that if the delay in response is more than 10 seconds, Grails is automatically sending a 500 error response.

Is that normal? If not, how do I extend that to longer period?

```
class StockController {

    def stock(String ticker) {
        task {
            sleep(30000) // introduce 30 second delay.
            ticker = ticker ?: 'GOOG'
            def url = new URL("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=${ticker}&f=nsl1op&e=.csv")
            Double price = url.text.split(',')[-1] as Double
            render "ticker: $ticker, price: $price"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the timeout is specific to the servlet container, not Grails itself.

Comment: You should configurate your servlet container for longer response time.